# Optimization algorithms in Optaplanner

Tags: optaplanner

I would like to ask how can I recognize which **optimization algorithms** were used when **Optaplanner** was solving 
any of built in examples ?  E.g there are `VRP with 25 customers or 400 customers with time window it is used`
same optimization algorithms for both ? I know that there is benchmark procedure which should be able to prefer the best solution but I don’t know which one was used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at [vehicleRoutingSolverConfig.xml](https://github.com/droolsjbpm/optaplanner/blob/master/optaplanner-examples/src/main/resources/org/optaplanner/examples/vehiclerouting/solver/vehicleRoutingSolverConfig.xml) for the one that is used in the GUI and look at the benchmark configs in [this directory](https://github.com/droolsjbpm/optaplanner/tree/master/optaplanner-examples/src/main/resources/org/optaplanner/examples/vehiclerouting/benchmark) for the different configs that were tried (and to run them locally to see which one is better).

Normally, the config with the best average score on all benchmark datasets is the one used in the solverConfig.xml that is used in the GUI.